# In PyCharm works fine when typing numbers in one by one, but won't work on code lab

Tags: python-3.x

Write a loop that reads positive integers from standard input and that terminates when it reads an integer that is not positive. After the loop terminates, it prints out, on a line by itself, the sum of all the even integers read.

```
number =int(input())
even_number = 0
while number >= 0:
    if number % 2 == 0:
        even_number += number
        print(even_number)
    number = int(input())
```

it says:

```
Exception occurred(, EOFError('EOF when reading a line',), )
Exception occurred(, EOFError('EOF when reading a line',), )
The value of _stdout is incorrect.
We think you might want to consider using: >
We think you might want to consider using: sum
We think you might want to consider using: +
Solutions with your approach don't usually use: +=
```

Answer (score 0):

> **After the loop terminates**, it prints out, on a line by itself, the sum of all the even integers read.

You seem to be printing each time the sum is updated, instead of just once at the end of the loop. Try moving the `print` to after the `while` block.